Why are Cassandra 4.0 configuration properties like enable_sasi_indexes no longer in 4.1?
I have been asked several times by users why certain configuration properties in Cassandra 4.0 conf/cassandra.yaml are no longer in 4.1.
For example, the flag which enables the experimental SASI feature:
enable_sasi_indexes: false

Where did these properties go?

Over the years, configuration items and JVM options have been added to Apache Cassandra. Given the open-source nature of the project, contributors freely named the properties and options. Since they don't follow a convention, the unintended consequence is that sometimes they don't make sense to the casual user.
In Cassandra 4.1, a new version of the configuration file cassandra.yaml was introduced with the goal of standardising the configuration properties and JVM options (CASSANDRA-15234).
Configuration properties like enable_sasi_indexes has been renamed to sasi_indexes_enabled:
sasi_indexes_enabled: false

The list of changes are documented on the Apache Cassandra website. This significant change to cassandra.yaml was also documented on the project's NEWS.txt on GitHub (release notes).
Please make sure to always consult the relevant versions NEWS.txt particularly before performing an upgrade. Cheers!
